# Multiple Grids search, filter and pagination don't work correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, search, grid, pagination

I added a second grid to the Catalog -> Manage Products page.  This new grid (Grid 2) references a collection other than Catalog/Product.  The old grid (Grid 1) I did not change.

When I load the page, both grids appear, with the top 20 items per collection.  Everything appears normal here.

When I try to search in Grid 2, a second Grid 1 appears and the page will not finish loading, it gets stuck in a continuous loop.

I have added the new grid as a child of the Catalog Product block

```
    //this line already existed       
    $this->setChild('grid', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_grid', 'product.grid'));
    //this is the line I added
    $this->setChild('newgrid', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('namespace_module/catalog_new_grid', 'new.grid'));
```

The grid does not appear to have the same id as the existing one:

```
    //new grid block
    public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('newGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('new_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setVarNameFilter('new_filter');

}
    //existing grid block        
    public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('productGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setVarNameFilter('product_filter');

}
```

I have a feeling the searching/pagination buttons are just referencing the wrong grid, but I'm not sure where/how to fix that.  Any thoughts on why Grid 2 doesn't search, filter or paginate and instead returns Grid 1?

Comment: could you maybe give us your complete code that you have inplace

Comment: Is there a particular piece of code you are looking for?  I'd rather not post the complete code as it contains some sensitive information.  If you can direct me to the type of code or file that could be helpful I can review and remove anything sensitive.